# Is it possible to send a text as my un-rooted device is shutting down using Tasker or any other method?

Tags: sms, tasker, automation, shutdown

I've set up a `Device Shutdown` event on Tasker, and I'm trying to use it to send an SMS text before the device dies due to the battery dying. I've got:

```
Event: Device Shutdown -> Task: Phone: Send SMS
```

`Send SMS` is set up currently to just send to myself for testing, but it's not working. I was hoping to have it send a text to the last sender if the last text received was less than 10 minutes ago, and the battery is below 3%, but I can't even get it to just send a simple text without conditions.

According to the tasker help file:

> The phone is about to shutdown (completely turned off, not standby).
>
> Note: this is right before shutdown. You might backup a file or
>   similar, but UI interactions such as dialogs and anything that takes a
>   significant amount of time will not work.

From this note, my guess is that `Send SMS` takes too long to execute, however I thought I'd throw this question out anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `State > Battery Level` as a profile context with minimum and maximum battery as 3%.

In the task, You can use `%SMSRN` to get phone number of last received SMS.

Then to check the condition of whether Last SMS text is received less than 10 minutes.

`%TIMES` has the current time in seconds. You need to use Variable Convert 
to get `%SMSRT` time in seconds and then do maths on the two values,

You can also use the / and % maths operator to get things like 'remaining minutes'.